# Ionic app splash screen crash

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm making a Ionic app that's working fine but after a few days of tests it crashes on the splash screen. It's quite strange as it worked perfectly for a few days.

Did anyone face the same issue, if yes how did you solve it? If not does anyone have an idea of where it might come from?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Quite impossible to answer. First thing i would do is to read the logs (JS and native layer).

Comment: The problem is that when I reinstall the app on the device it doesn't crash anymore, so I would need to wait until it crashes again to read the logs.